# C# Datetime doesn't show correctly

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two date time strings likes

```
string firstDate = "2013-08-05 14:00:00.000";
string secondDate ="2013-08-03 13:16:02.740";


DateTime.Parse(firstDate).ToShortTimeString() => 2:00 PM
```

firstDate show correctly ,but

```
DateTime.Parse(secondDate).ToShortTimeString() => 12:00 AM
```

What I'm wrong here ? I want to show `secondDate` likes `1:16 PM` .

Comment: And what do you get instead of 1:16 PM?

Comment: Thats strange are you sure about the time part of the second date ? Hope it is not written as `DateTime.Parse(secondDate).Date.ToShortTimeString()`

Comment: It works fine for me.. 12.00 AM is the default time for a DateTime I believe.. are you setting it correctly?

Comment: No repro... Are you really sure? Try a `ToString()` instead of a `ToShortTimeString()`

Comment: This is strange. I did try exactly the same just now and I did get the expected output "1:16 PM"

Comment: @MaheshVelaga , can you show me your code as answer ?

Comment: @zey, The code I used was your code, copy and pasted into Console app

Comment: var firstDate = "2013-08-05 14:00:00.000";
var secondDate ="2013-08-03 13:16:02.740";

System.Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(firstDate).ToShortTimeString());
System.Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(secondDate).ToShortTimeString());

Comment: I used linqpad to execute this and write the output to console. Are you using anything else in conjunction with these calls, like using the output of your second statement in some other logic?

Comment: @Sayse , what's the output ? `1:16 PM` ? or `12:00 AM` ?

Comment: "13.16", that would be using my current culture though, See my first comment, 12.00 AM I believe is the default time for a date time, Try copying your own code into a new console application too and then write it with console.writeline

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can specify a lot more formats than just the method overloads .NET has

`.ToString("h:mm tt");`

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
DateTime.Parse(secondDate).ToString("h:mm tt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
  DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(secondDate);
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(1033);

  string secondDateTime = dt.ToShortTimeString();
```